# R Evaluate if a Value Exists in Another Table

Tags: r

**df1:**

```
a = c(2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12) 
b = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb","aa") 
c = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) 
df1 = data.frame(a, b, c)
```

**df2:**

```
df2 = c("aa", "bb")
```

I want to evaluate df1$b to see if the value is in df2$d. If it is, then keep the value. If it's not then input "Rare"

**Output:
df1**

```
a  b    c
2  aa   true
3  bb   false
5  rare true
8  aa   false
10 bb   true
12 aa   false
```

Comment: `df1$b[!df1$b %in% df2] <- "rare"` (Btw, `df2` is a vector here not a frame. If it's really a frame with a column named `x`, then `!df1$b %in% df2$x`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in `base R`:

```
#Data
a = c(2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12) 
b = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb","aa") 
c = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) 
df1 = data.frame(a, b, c,stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(d=c("aa", "bb"),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Compute
df1$b <- ifelse(df1$b %in% df2$d,df1$b,'rare')
```

Output:

```
   a    b     c
1  2   aa  TRUE
2  3   bb FALSE
3  5 rare  TRUE
4  8   aa FALSE
5 10   bb  TRUE
6 12   aa FALSE
```

Comment: Also works with `df1$b[!df1$b %in% df2$d] <- 'rare'`

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` way would look the following:

```
# Load library
library(data.table)

# Convert created tables to data.table object
setDT(df1)

# Add 'rare' 
df1[!b %in% df2, b := "rare"]
```

If `df2` is a table (not a vector like it is in the original post and the code chunk above), then you should reference the appropriate column. For example, `df2$b`

The outcome:

```
> df1
    a    b     c
1:  2   aa  TRUE
2:  3   bb FALSE
3:  5 rare  TRUE
4:  8   aa FALSE
5: 10   bb  TRUE
6: 12   aa FALSE
```